# jqGrid Data Validation using editrules doesn't validate the entire form

Tags: javascript, validation, jqgrid

I would like to understand how and when the data validation happens in jqgrid. 
I would like to capture all the error messages in 1 go instead of giving 1 error message at a time.

For e.g. My edit rules are all defined in the colModel. but the error message comes for the 1st element and after correcting that error, then for the second element. 
Is there a way, i can list all error messages for the auto generated edit form.

Comment: Look at [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6814804/315935) which describes the workaround which you can use. [Another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6162086/315935) can give you tip how you can mark the fields having errors.

Comment: Oleg, thanks for your response, I am still not very clear about how to go about it. I did take a look at your demo and my question is how would you be able to give all error messages if http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithInlineEditing.htm for amount,tax and total as a single messages instead of the 3 layered error messages currently