# jqGrid - Save row after edit using a custom button

Tags: button, jqgrid, rows, inline-editing

I'm using jqGrid, and I need to do the things below:

I need to edit the rows (using inline editing), and after that (after I edit, the data have to be stored in local mode just for visualization) and after that I have to be able to edit another row (and the things have to happen the same way). After I edit the rows, I'd like to visualize all the rows and just after that I'd press a button to save my changes in the database.

How can I do that?

Comment: Why wouldn't you want your changes to be saved per row as you preform them?

Comment: You would probably be much better to have a confirmation screen or checks on the data entered then to have all the changes saved locally and then populated back to the database as a whole....

Comment: Huuumm. I'm sorry @Mark, but how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand, saving your edits for post will potentially result in syncronization errors especially if multiple users are operating on the same records.  If you want to use Form Editing you can look at a `beforeSubmit` event to visually display the row to the user to ask them to confirm changes.  If it is format, or other things you are looking to verify you can look at custom cell validation such as in the following link:

[how to implement row level validation in jqgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6814230/how-to-implement-row-level-validation-in-jqgrid)

Comment: If this leads you to your answer please mark as correct (as well as giving the linked post an update).  Oleg has a ton of answers on here as well around custom cell validation.